# Prove Two Equivalence Relations are Equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm doing a self-study through Velleman's "How to Prove It" and am working through exercises on equivalence relations.  My proof for the statement below seems unconvincing, and am wondering if someone can help me fill the gaps in the argument. Thanks in advance!

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on $A$ and $A/R = A/S$.  Prove that $R = S$.

Proof: Let $(x, y)$ be an element of $R$.  Since $R$ is an equivalence relation, then $x \sim y$, and so $x \in [y]_R$ and $y \in [y]_R$. By definition of $A/R$, we can choose some $X \in A/R$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are elements of $X$.  But since $X \in A/R$,  then $X \in A/S$. And since $S$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, and $x \in X$ and $y \in X$, then $(x, y)$ is also an element of $S$.  Since $(x, y)$ is an arbitrary element of $R$, we have $R \subset S$.  The proof for $S \subset R$ proceeds in the same manner.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Perfectly correct. It could be a little more concise. Something like: Suppose $(x,y) \in R$. Then for some $X \in A/R$, both $x \in X$ and $y \in X$. But then $x, y$ are in the same $S$-equivalence class $X \in A/S = A/R$, so $(x,y) \in S$. Thus, $R \subseteq S$. Similarly, $S \subseteq R$.

Comment: Thank you both the comments!  Much appreciated.  And Brian, thank you for providing a revised a more concise version.  The arguments makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to look at this is to note that if you are given
$A/R$, where $R$ is an equivalence relation, then
$R = \cup_{P \in A/R} (P \times P)$. It follows immediately from this that
if $A/R = A/S$ then $R=S$.